# How to check all items of a list in python are equal to a?

Tags: python

Ok in my script I need it that say base is an array but the ammount of numbers in it can be anything. I want something that can check all items of the list to see if all eliments = 5 heres an example

```
base = [5, 5, 5, 5]
```

What code can i use to return a statement that all the numbers are equal to 5.

Comment: `if item in base != 5:` or `while item in bade != 5:`?

Comment: What's with your site? dancing-nerds.net?

Comment: lol its one of those website that you make and host but never did anything with XD

Comment: What do you use to host and where did you get your domain?

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax Why are you so intrested in my site?

Comment: Because I wanted to start one, but don't know where to start...

Comment: Well I made mine on https://www.blacknight.com but I wouldnt recomend it as there basic package dosent give root access

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax That's offtopic. Please ask your own question so that others may help you. Or better yet, since it's been asked before, search for it.

Comment: @personjerry Yeah ask a question like that and your rep will drop quick

Comment: Anyway i treid if item in base !=5: and it gave me an errorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PyCharm Files/ZFast/zfast.py", line 20, in <module>
    if item in base != 5:
NameError: name 'item' is not defined

Comment: @zac do personjerry answer then add mine under it like `for i in base:` then `if i not in base:`

Comment: @zac actually go with Daniel's answer it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `all`-function:

```
if all(b==5 for b in base):
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible short solution:

```
k = [5,5,5,5]
answer = 5
k == [answer for i in range(len(k))] # evaluates to True
```