# Is there a fast way of getting the overall boolean in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, vector, boolean

I have an array consisting of booleans like: `[False, True, True, False,...]` and so on. I wonder if it is possible to "and" combine them all in a fast way in python. I do not want to bound to a certain kind of variable like in this question: [check all items if they are equal to a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725443/how-to-check-all-items-of-a-list-in-python-are-equal-to-a) . This is only for boolean, like in the question described. The answers from this previous question do not refer to booleans. So sth like:

```
ray = [True,True,True]


for i in range(1,len(ray)):
    t = ray[i] and ray[i-1]
```

But in a fancy python one-line style.

Comment: You can check `all` and `any`.

Comment: As mentioned by @Psidom, use `all(ray)` for all true

Comment: Thank you! I have not known about this command

Comment: `len(set(ray)) == 1`

Comment: In my opinion this is not a duplicate due to : 1) The other question refers to any kind of variable, this is only refering to booleans, 2) The other answers do not provide the "all" operator, (of course, they do not see reason 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function.